# session data lost after session regeneration in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have regenerated my session on login page and set session["xx"}="yy"; in some of the variables.
but after redirecting to home page session data is lost.
Can anyone tell me about this problem. Here is the code for session regeneration.

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
manager.RemoveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var newId = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var isRedirected = true;
var isAdded = true;
manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newId, out isRedirected, out isAdded);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create and set the new sessionId, old sessions will not work with new sessionid.
So,First you need to destroy the session cookie, then we recreate a new sessionID before redirecting to login page.
You can try this:

```
Session.Abandon();
Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
manager.RemoveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var newId = manager.CreateSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
var isRedirected = true;
var isAdded = true;
manager.SaveSessionID(System.Web.HttpContext.Current, newId, out isRedirected, out isAdded);
Response.Redirect("Login page url");
```